# How do SMS and MMS URL Link Previews Work on Mobile Devices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, twilio-api

If i send manually html URL link (which is accessible from public) to between the mobiles as a SMS, i am getting preview of the HTML. but if i integrate service in Java and send the SMS, i am getting exactly link not preview. presently i am using Twilio.

```
``TwilioRestClient2 client = new TwilioRestClient2(AccountSid,AuthToken);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", to));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", fromNumber));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", message));
MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();
Message twilioMessage = messageFactory.create(params);``
```

If we want to get html preview, what exactly we need to do ?? Twilio won't support this ?? if not any other services will support ?? please suggest me to go forward.

Comment: adding of the above code, in the body i am try to sending public link "http://*****-public.s3.amazonaws.com/vehicles/test.html". below is the html file               
 <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">

  <head>

    <meta property="og:title" content="Mark's Favorites at AEO" />

    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://www.j-26.com/assets/twitter.jpg"/>

  </head>

  <body>

    <p>Web page content goes here</p>

  </body>

</html>
if i sending manually i am getting preview, but twilo or Amazon SNS i am getting plain message. did i miss any thing.

Comment: Please avoid adding additional information to your question in the comments. Instead, edit your question and add the information there. Cheers :)

Comment: How are you sending the link? Are you sending the html source code in the SMS?

Comment: Sure, sorry for that. I am not sending source code I am sending html link,HTML page is in public access site. Manually if I send link as message, it’s working fine, I can see preview. But when I send Using Twilio or aws SNS it is coming as a plain html link as a message, you can see source code if html page which I created. Did I miss any thing ?? Do I want to add any other task to support using Twilio or Aws SNS? Please advise me

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet sure whether I understood what you are doing, but let me try my best to answer your question.

Messaging applications usually parse the message and look for anything that looks like a URL. When they find a URL in the message, they make it appear as a link. The underlying message though is still plain text, no html is involved. Therefore, your message should be something like

```
Hey, I have a cool link for you, click here: https://google.com
```

and not

```
Hey, I have a cool link for you, click here: <a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, want to give brief idea again: I don’t have problem with creating html. I am not sending source code directly the body.  Here I am doing the things , I am uploading my html into public access site, I am sending html path in the body, this path is http. Using Twilio I am getting exactly the whole link as a message, when I try to use same link manually to one mobile to other mobile sms, I am getting preview of the html.  Now the problem is why I am not getting same preview while using twilio or Aws SNS. Hope you understand now

Comment: Thank you, I got the info. we cant proceed with preview for unknown numbers. my question is invalid. thanks for helping me.